# Issues with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am currently trying to create a mail client and I need to store mails in a database.

I am using the [MailKit library](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) from Github and I'm trying to save a `MimeMessage` but I get an error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   MailAppTest.MimeMessage: : EntityType 'MimeMessage' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   MailAppTest.InternetAddress: : EntityType 'InternetAddress' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.     (And some more)

I know this means that the primary key wasn't found but I can't create id keys because I can't change the original classes.

Is there something I could do?

Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: overwrite the modelbuilder with modelbuilder.Entity<T>().HasKey();

Comment: Create a separate entity and map the email model to that entity.

Comment: Like @Cameron suggested, this would be the way to go. This way, you gain control over what is stored, and how - which is a good thing ;)

The class you are trying to "save" probably was never designed for this kind of serialization and therefore might yield other problems.


This approach often has the side-effect of writing "quite some lines" of boilerplate-code, as property-names do not differ from one another.

[Automapper](http://automapper.org/) might help here.